# make javascript preform an action based on input in drop down menus

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu

I have been trying to make a little web page where you select two items from a drop down menu and press a button and it plays a sound, the sound varying based on what is selected in the drop down menu. Unfortunately I am having trouble with getting my JavaScript to interact with the button and then getting JavaScript to exert what is selected in the drop down.

Here are some snippets of my basic code:

HTML:

```
<head>
    <script src="src/EEEE.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="image" id="button" value="submit" src="img/Button.png" onclick="handleClick()"/>
    <br>
    <select id="who">
        <option value="name1">Name 1</option>
        <option value="name2">Name 2</option>
        <option value="name3">Name 3</option>
    </select>
    <select id="what">
        <option value="op1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="op2">Option 2</option>
        <option value="op3">Option 3</option>
    </select>
</body>
```

JavaScript (in a folder called "src"):

```
function handleClick(){
    var w1 = document.getElementById("who").value;
    var name = who.options[who.selectedIndex].text;
    if(name == "name1"){
        /*do this*/
    }else if(name == "name2"){
        /*do that*/
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have fixed your code, you can see the fixed demo [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/TheBanana/a6kj6/1/)

basically you should have used `'value'` instead of `'text'` and attaching event via javscript seems to work.

Comment: Thank you, hopefully I should be able to use it now

Comment: you are welcomed. if my answer helped, please consider accepting it by clicking the green V on the left :)

Comment: Woops, forgot about that :)

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery makes it easy:

```
$('#button').click(function(){
    dd1Val = $('#who').val();
    dd2Val = $('#what').val();
    alert(dd1Val + "" + dd2Val);
})
```

Comment: if op wanted it in jQuery he would have tagged it jQuery

Comment: and if op has never heard of jQuery?

Comment: if you read his question again, you might notice that op asks for help with getting javscript to interact with the button.

Comment: you do realize that jquery is javascript. i would have hesitated if he asked specifically for a native js solution.

Comment: jquery is an extension script which many prefer not to use or are unable to use due to restrictions put on them. if he didnt specifically ask for jQuery solution, your answer does not solve his problem. you could however, give him a javscript solution and suggest jQuery as alternative.

Comment: I have heard of jQuery but at this point I do not plan on getting in to it (though I suppose it won't be that hard)